# Navigation graphics overlayed over video

Tags: c++, python, graphics, video, video-processing

Imagine I have a video playing.. Can I have some sort of motion graphics being played 'over' that video.. Like say the moving graphics is on an upper layer than the video, which would be the lower layer..

I am comfortable in a C++ and Python, so a solution that uses these two will be highly appreciated..

Thank you in advance,
Rishi..

Comment: *Do* you have a video playing? How are you playing it? If not, what kind of platform would you like to use? As-is, I would say to use a shiny television screen and a mirror.

Comment: Was the question really answered or not at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly but a video file is a sequence of pictures that you can extract (for instance with the opencv library C++ interface) and then you can use it wherever you want. You can play the video on the sides of an opengl 3D cube (available in all opengl tutorials) and other 3D elements around it.

Of course you can also displays it in a conventional 2D interface and draw stuff on top of it, but for this you need a graphical ui.

Is it what you thought or am I completely lost?

Comment: Yes Nikko you are completely right.. but more so in the second paragraph.. Display the video in a conventional 2D interface.. and then draw stuff on top of it.. And you said for that I'd need a graphical UI. Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: You need a graphical interface to display your images (like Qt, gtkmm in c++, ...). But with a library like opencv (but there are others), you can extract images from a video file (but also a video device), modify them (like drawing lines, add blur, draw text) and then send it to your graphical interface.

If you think opencv is a bit too complex, you can edit your images with a library like ImageMagick (Magick++ for C++) which may be simpler and easy for basic tasks.